# How to filter data with given numerator and denominator coefficients of an IIR Filter, in MATLAB Implement

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, digital-filter

----------Added at 2019/9/2 22:36;

An important but missing information seems to be the order of my filter. I designed my filter with numerator and denominator length both equal to 20, so the order is 38. Specific coefficients are shown in the following image:[filter coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZHAM.jpg).

----------Added at 2019/9/2 18:42; 1st updated at 9/2 22:51;

According to @Irreducible, I add the magnitude of the unfiltered signal and the filtered signal as follow. As it was figured in 'filtering result' image, the magnitude of unfiltered signal kept at a level of less than 0.1 and got an mean value of 1.9337e-07, while the magnitude of the filtered signal seemed to be amplified to 'Nan' level by simply having a glance of `mean(filt)` or `mean(filt_sos)` and got 'NaN' as result.

For more information, see 'filt' data [filt data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FxCV.jpg), or the magnitude comparison among 'unfiltered raw signal','filtered signal using filter()' and 'filtered signal using sosfilt()' [unfiltered, filt, filt_sos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWIWc.jpg).

Using dB scale and cut off y-axis, plot the magnitude of unfiltered and filtered signal again [dB-scale and truncated-y-axis filtered signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD9TQ.jpg). As shown in the image, from certain time on, the magnitude would keep at 'NaN' level.

But according to magnitude response of the filter, it should amplify the raw data with no more than 30 dB. So I thought there must be something wrong here.

---

**1. Problem description**

I'm trying to filter data with an IIR filter, with using `Y=filter(b,a,X)` in MATLAB. I've got the numerator and denominator coefficients, and with `freqz(b,a)` I'm sure this is the filter I need. However, after I do `filter(b,a,sig)`, the output seemed to be beyond my expectation. I've worked on it a few days with no progress.

Anyone may help me out here? What's wrong with my code, or what's the exactly right way to use numerator and denominator coefficients to filter data?

**2. Main code**

Here is my code, for brevity, I omit some coefs:

```
clear;close all;clc;
%%% load data
[wav,Fs]= audioread('G:\Program\MATLAB\wavEQ\Experiment\raw.wav'); 
sig = wav(:,1);                           % data to be filtered
%%% get numerator and denominator coefficients
allCoef = [9.022012513759181  0.48509530946330026  ...];
len_b = ceil(length(allCoef)/2);
b = allCoef(1:len_b);
a(1) = 1;
a(2:length(allCoef)-len_b+1)= allCoef(len_b+1:length(allCoef));
%%% filtering
filt = filter(b, a, sig);                % IIR filtering
%%% sos-type filtering
[SOS,~] = tf2sos(b,a);
filt_sos = sosfilt(SOS, sig);
%%% figure
figure;
subplot(311)
plot(sig);title('orgin signal');
subplot(312)
plot(filt);title('filt');
subplot(313)
plot(filt_sos);title('filt_sos');
% wav_filtering = [sig1_filtering,wav(:,2)];
% audiowrite('raw_FIR_filtering.wav', wav_filtering, Fs);
```

**3. Filtering result**

With `freqz(b,a)` or `fvtool(b,a)`, I'm pretty sure this is the mag-response I need:
[magnitude response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiDFh.jpg)

The filtering result was as follow:
[filtering result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzKH3.jpg)

The filtering signal's amplitude was much higher than the origin signal's, which was quite not consistent with the mag-response evidently.

By the way, the frequency of the origin signal is between 0 and 10000 Hz, the sampling rate of raw data is 51200 Hz, and the sampling frequency of my IIR filter is 51200 Hz.

**4. My consideration**

Firstly, I thought there must be something wrong with my usage of `filter(b,a,X)`, then I `help filter` and learn that "The filter is a 'Direct Form II Transposed' implementation of the standard difference equation:". I tried to convert coefficients to SOS type with `[sos,~]=tf2sos(b,a)`, but the filtering result was still far from expectation (using `sosfilt(sos)`).

I couldn't help believing that I may have trouble with understanding the relationship between transfer function and coefficients of the filters. But what happened with `filter(b,a,X)` since I could get ideal frequency response using these b & a with `freqz(b,a)`. Are b and a in these two functions represent different things? Any suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. On the first glance I dont have the impression, that there is anything wrong with the filtering (filter or sosfilt). Having a look at your magnitude response of your filter, you can see that you are mainly amplifying your signal with upto 30 dB. So, it is no surprise that your amplitude of the filtered signal will be higher than the one of the original signal. So the question should be, why did you expect any other result ? You should add the magnitude of the unfiltered signal and the filtered signal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention!  I've added the magnitude information to the question. As it is updated, the magnitude of unfiltered signal is no more than 0.1, with an average of 1.9337e-07. However the magnitude of the filtered signal could be amplified to 'Nan' or 'Inf' level while the designed filter, as you said, gets no more than 30 dB gain at certain frequency.

Comment: I am sorry to inform you, but the figures you added are terrible. You should not plot them on a linear scale but rather use a dB scale, additionally having extrem values I higly recommend to clip them by limiting the y-axis, otherwise you wont see anything. An important information is also missing, which order has your filter? And finally you should consider to ask this question at [DSP SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions), as this is rather a signal processing and not programming question.

Comment: You're right, sir. I'm fairly weak in FILTER or DSP subject, and this is my first time to ask question on SO. Sorry for my unprofessionalism and super super appreciated for your help and guidance. I take your advice and plot figures with dB scale, also truncate the y-axis, some magnitude of the filtered signal keep at NaN level. By the way, about the order of my filter, Numerator Length and Denominator Length both are 20, so may be 38th order. My silly problem might disturb you a lot, I would consider asking it at DSP SE as you recommended.